# Redirect user to homepage after login

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am creating a web portal. The JavaScript that displays the homepage of the web portal is sensitive and must only be displayed to authenticated users.

I currently have two HTML files: login.html and homepage.html

When someone navigates to my app at portal.com/homepage, it redirects the user to portal.com/login

In order to cause the redirect, I am using lambda.

Once the user has logged in, I wish to redirect them to portal.com/homepage.

However, with the current headers that are being passed to the lambda through API Gateway, I have no way of authenticating the user and so cannot know whether the user is logged in.

I would like to know how to redirect my user to the homepage and forward the session information to the lambda so that my lambda can authenticate the user and return the html rather than redirecting to the login page.

Invoking the API with the client side JavaScript just returns the html file to the variable that called it rather than opening it in a new page.

Below are my lambdas:

```
  exports.login = (event, context, callback) => {

  const poolId = ** value that tells me a user is authenticated **

  let contents = ""
  let result = {}

  if (poolId) {
    result = {
      statusCode:302,
      headers: {
        poolId,
        "Location": "https://portal.com/homepage"
      },
    }
  } else {
    contents = fs.readFileSync(`app/login.html`);
    result = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: contents.toString(),
      headers: {'content-type': 'text/html'}
    };
  }

  callback(null, result);
};

exports.hoempage = (event, context, callback) => {

  const poolId = ** value that tells me my user is authenticated**

  let result = {}
  let contents = ""
  if (poolId) {

    contents = fs.readFileSync(`app/homepage.html`);

    result = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify([event, context]),
      headers: {'content-type': 'text/html'}
    }

  } else {
    result = {
      statusCode:302,
      headers: {
        "Location": "https://portal.com/login"
      }
    }

  }

  callback(null, result)
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

on the backend you can send you jwt tocken, validate the tocken if the session is expired redirect the user to login page otherwise keep him hanging around in your system.
see the following is the tocken validation mechanism.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

Comment: How can you send the token to the backend on a redirect with js?

Comment: in header set the value for "Authentication" Key. then in the backend you can extract the value of Authentication from request header.

Comment: A redirection in the HTTP protocol doesn't support adding any headers to the target location. I've found a solution using Lambda@edge though. Thank you for the help